# Redireccionamiento de página

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código, y necesito que al encontrarse en la página en idioma español, redireccione a la página de agradecimientos en ese idioma, y al encontrarse en la página en inglés, lo propio.

Por el momento no funciona y sólo redirecciona todas las veces a la página en inglés.

Ya intenté agregar un `else if` con la ruta `http://ejemplo.com/es` (que es donde se encuentra la página en español), pero tampoco hay caso.

```
function backupPost(user_data){
console.log(user_data);
$.ajax({
  url: "/new_one",
  type: "POST",
  data: user_data,
  success: function(){
    // console.log('OK');
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("http://ejemplo.com/") > -1){
      window.location.href = "/en/thankyou";
    }
    else {
      window.location.href = "/gracias";
    }
  },

  error: function(data){
    // console.log(data);
    console.log('ERROR');

  },
  statusCode:{
    409: function(){
      alert('Duplicated User');
    }
  }
});  
}
```

Comment: Idealmente, tu página debería tener un atributo `lang` que indique el idioma del documento, y que sería una mejor opción que intentar detectar el idioma basándose en la URL en la que te encuentres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta asi :

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/es") > -1){
  window.location.href = "/es/gracias";
}
else {
  window.location.href = "/en/thankyou";
}
```

Comment: Excelente Mauricio. Funcionó a la perfección. Muchas gracias!